# How to block sending outgoing mail from other domains in from field

Tags: postfix-mta

In my postfix mail server, users are able to send mail on name of different domains
using from field in mail client software.

For eg. I am using sendEmail mail client, and I can send emails with hdfc.com domain or other too,

> sendEmail -v -f "amit@hdfc.com" -s "test.example.in:25" -xu "amit" -xp "ami*321" -t "xyz@yahoo.co.in"  -u "test from sendEmaili 0255" -m "this is sendEmail test"

This mail goes to spam and it did not show actual mail address in details header.

How Can I restrict my outgoing mails such that it can only send outgoing mails which have my domain  test.example.in? or it would be great if I can map user's too that user can't use other users name.

If only first case work that will be sufficient for me.

I searched a lot but not able to do this. my postfix version is 2.11.3-1 on debian Jessie. My setup have just postfix with sasl authentication, authentication is working fine.

--
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To block from address which don't match with user email account, below line did the magic. Add this in main.cf

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated
```

**To map system users to email address**

1. add the line in main.conf

below file we used to map system users to email address

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/envelope_senders
```

2. Map the system user to email address in /etc/postfix/envelope_senders file, amit is my system user

`amit@test.example.in amit`

3. Run the below command, you can add other system users too, whenever you edit this file, you have to run below command and reload the postfix

`postmap /etc/postfix/envelope_senders`
and reload postfix
`postfix reload`

it's done, now no one can use other email address than amit@test.example.in in from field, if he tried to use anything it will reject the email.

Comment: Note that `smtpd_sender_login_maps` applies to envelope addresses (AKA "MAIL FROM") only. Users could still forge the "From:" header (AKA "RFC5322.From").